# HTML5/Javascript - My simple canvas animation isn't working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I thought this would be the kind of thing there would be plenty of tutorials on, however every one I found was either over-complicated, vague, or used features not yet widely supported. So, I decided to try it on my own. My code is below.

```
function drawStuff(){
var x = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvas = x.getContext('2d');

var i;

function animate(){
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    canvas.fillStyle="red";
    canvas.fillRect(0,i,50,50);
    i++;
}

    windows.setInterval(animate(), 125);
}
window.addEventListener("load", drawStuff, false);
```

Why isn't this working? Do I misunderstand what the setInterval does? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A little late, but in line 2 it is preferred to put context not canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, set value to variable i

Comment: Which value? There's several

Comment: initialize your variable i to 0 or whatever starting value you need.

Comment: Ah. This(along with steveukx pointing out a typo)fixed it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in that you refer to `windows` rather than `window`, and the argument supplied should be a reference to the function you want to run, so it should be `animate` rather than `animate()` which would just call the animate function immediately.

Those two changes should make:

```
window.setInterval(animate, 125);
```